# TinyMCE Editor - multiple text selections

Tags: text, tinymce, editor, selection

Is it possible to provide the user the ability to select multiple words in TinyMCE editor? It is possible in Word when holding the CTRL button. So, can I make the same in this editor?

[Example in Word - Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjKb7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can select them, but you are not able to apply formats or anything else on it. The first selection is taken only.

Comment: Thanks :( Is there an editor with multiple selections and applying formats? No?

Comment: CKEditor seems to act on more than just the first selection: http://ckeditor.com/demo